# What is version of Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

One of our previous developer used this class but i couldn't find the zend version and documentation of this class

`use Core\Db\BaseModels\BaseDbTable;`

Please bear with me i have just started my zf training

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a `Zend-Framework` class. The namespace of all Zend classes start with `Zend\`.
Similarly, all Laminas (Zend migrated to Laminas) classes namespaces start with `Laminas\`.

Beside that, Zend-Framework has not a "version" anymore since 2017 (when version 2.4.13 was released).

Then is not a "monolithic" framework, but it has been divided in packages (based on functionnalities/features), meaning that the "zend version" depends on what package you are using.

To understand what package you are looking for, you have to dig inside `Core\Db\BaseModels\BaseDbTable` and see which zend classes it uses. From that, you have to search inside `vendor/zend/` directory where this classes are located, and from that you have the package your application is using.

Finally, when you have the package (which may probably be `zendframework/zend-db`), you must look in `composer.lock` file to get what version is installed:

```json
...
{
    "name": "laminas/laminas-db",
    "version": "2.11.3",
    ...
}
...
```